# Angular displaying the wrong date

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have an app with an Angular 7 front end and a back-end consisting of a Microsoft Web API utilizing Entity Framework Code First connected to a sql database. I have a column with data stored as a DATE type. When I access the data using `{{myDate}}` it displays `2020-04-05T00:00:00Z`, but if I use `{{myDate | date}}` it displays `4/04/20`.

The first date April 5th is correct, but the second date created via the pipe is displaying April 4th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue from angular. I suspect it's because of your timezone

```
A timezone offset (such as '+0430'), 
or a standard UTC/GMT or continental US timezone abbreviation. 
**When not supplied, uses the end-user's local system timezone.**

Optional. Default is undefined.
```

For example in my case `{{'2020-04-05T00:00:00Z' | date:'full'}}` gives `Sunday, April 5, 2020 at 2:00:00 AM GMT+02:00` and `{'2020-04-05T00:00:00Z' | date:'full':'UTC'}}`gives `Sunday, April 5, 2020 at 12:00:00 AM GMT+00:00`

I hope this helps.

Edit: `full` parameter will help you debug your issue better and then once you resolve it you can render something nicer to the user.